Norm of fractional Sobolev spaces
Let $\Omega$ a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with a decomposition $\bar{\Omega} = \bar{\Omega}_1 \cup \bar{\Omega}_2$ (with $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=\emptyset$), and let $s\in(0,1)$. Consider the space $\tilde{H^s}(\Omega)$ of functions $v$ in $H^s(\Omega)$ such that $\tilde{v}\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\tilde{v}$ is is the continuation of $v$ by 0 to $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega$. The space $\tilde{H^s}(\Omega)$ is endowed with norm $$\|v\|_{\tilde{H^s}(\Omega)}^2:=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^N\times \mathbb{R}^N}\frac{|\tilde{v}(x)-\tilde{v}(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}dxdy.$$
I am interested in the space  $X^s_{\Omega_1}:=\{ v|_{\Omega_1}; v \in \tilde{H^s}(\Omega)\}$, i.e., the restriction to $\Omega_1$ of functions in $\tilde{H^s}(\Omega)$.
What is the appropriate norm for this space? Should it be defined using an extension operator, or is there a more natural way to define the norm in terms of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N$ )? Specifically, how should the nonlocal contributions from points in $\Omega_2$ and  $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \Omega $ be handled in the norm of functions restricted to $\Omega_1 $?
Thank you very much in advance.
